# Will password complexity requirements increase or decrease security given a haveibeenpwned check?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

Given that you check that a password is not a common password and not present in a db with compromised passwords, will password complexity requirements (e.g. at least 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase character and 1 special character) reduce security by reducing the search space without any benefits?

> Note: Assume that passwords are hashed using bcrypt with a cost around 14-16.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16196/do-password-complexity-requirements-reduce-security-by-limiting-search-space?rq=1 The answers to this question are the same as the answers to the linked question, I believe.

Comment: @Adonalsium I took the "search space"-from that question, but the main point is that the answers there do not hold given a compromised password check at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Wanted to post my own reasoning in the question as I have given this some thought and the reason I am posting this as a question is to check my reasoning. For all I know this answer might get downvoted :) .

I mean, the general argument - as I understand it - is that password complexity requirements require the user to choose a password from a greater 'space', thus decreasing the chances of picking an unsafe password as a lot of unsafe passwords are only lowercase alpha (though clearly not all, such as `Password1!`).

When something like [haveibeenpawned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2) is checked that is an improved check removing the large majority of the "unsafe password"-space. Instead of considering all lowercase alpha passwords unsafe, it instead uses actual data to determine which passwords are or are not unsafe (the set of compromised passwords is assumed to be extremely similar to unsafe passwords). Combining both complexity rules with a compromised password database check thus primarily eliminates the 'secure' part of the lowercase alpha space, blocking safe passwords which are caught by password complexity rules such as passphrases (e.g. `catwindowlightpencil`).

[image]

*The above figure doesn't encompass all passwords, it instead compares the passwords password complexity rules are blocking with the passwords you wish to block. The unsafe password set is the one you wish to block, the compromised password set is a subset you can block, the lowercase alpha set is the one you block with password complexity rules.*

> Note: Obviously new 'dumb' passwords can be 'created'. For example, a new pop idol might become popular during the past week or Microsoft might buy Github, but not yet show up in a compromised password database. Similarly someone might use a product name as a password of a product that has not been compromised yet.

Comment: Should not the union be labelled 'dumb' passwords, and the right hand set be labelled something like 'large namespace passwords'?

Comment: @Adonalsium No, absolutely not, because `Password1!` is an extremely dumb password (thousands and thousands of compromised cases), but is not part of the typically blocked passwords. The point of the graphic is to point out that blocking lowercase alpha passwords doesn't achieve the goal you wish to achieve. It blocks passwords you don't want to block (`mycrazypassphrasetoiletbomb`) and it doesn't block passwords you want to block (`Password1!`).

Comment: @Adonalsium updated for added clarity.

Comment: But half the graph is about namespace and the other half is about quality of passwords

Comment: @Adonalsium They are both sets of passwords. One set is defined by 'quality', the other by characters used. The point is to show that 'characters used' is a bad proxy for 'quality'.

Comment: Your explanation, specifically "combining both thus only eliminates the 'secure' part of the lowercase alpha space, leaving safe passwords...", is not clear.  Are you saying combining them both is a good or bad thing?  Are you implying that if a password isn't in a particular compromised blacklist that it is secure, regardless of character construction?

Comment: @PwdRsch You're right, tried to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**Will it reduce the search space?**

***Yes***, but only an extremely small fraction of it will be eliminated: let's assume we consider *k* characters, of which 26 characters are lower case. Let us consider a password of *n* characters. The fraction of the search space that is being overlooked by rejecting lower case passwords would then be (26/k)^n.

For n=8 (which in most cases is the minimal length) and k=128 (which is the number of ASCII characters*), this results in a 2.9*10^-6 fraction of the search space.

**Will it reduce security?**

***No***, it will not, because the search space is virtually unaltered. The complexity of your password is still O(k^n).

*admitted, not all of them are suited for typing in a password, but most of them are

Comment: Well, it eliminates passphrases, which humans are biased to and are incredibly safe when used properly, without any of the major disadvantages of password managers (single point of failure primarily).

Comment: And that's the other thing, passphrases are long.

Comment: What you say is right, but your question was if it reduces security by reducing the search space; to that question, the answer is 'No, it is not noticeably easier to bruteforce a password that has complexity requirements'. But I agree the 'complexity requirements' could/should also take length into account (in some 'OR'-construction). Or checking to known weak passwords is interesting as well!

Comment: I agree, if the password requirements are disabled given sufficient length that kind of solves the main issue I see with them. Anyway, my main question is mostly about the interaction between a known weak password check and such password requirements. Like yes, statistically only a small fraction gets removed, but do you get any actual benefit by removing that small fraction given a known weak password check?

Comment: Well, yes; the benefit is there for people who: 1. Only use lower case, 2. Use a short password, AND 3. Use an 'unknown' password. Such as 'nkxlebtl'.